# How to prevent corruptions from spreading?

Tags: terraria

After my world turned to hardmode, hollow and crismon corruption began to spread. I tried destroying them using the clentaimator but after a few hours it starts to spread again.

I don't like my to be filled with corruption. The picture shows that I used solution to clean the crimson but soon after it started to spread once more.

What can i do to keep the crimson and hollow from spreading?

[picture http://upload7.ir/uploads//57252c66634678b0edadaf19c8926c1995117bce.jpg](http://upload7.ir/uploads//57252c66634678b0edadaf19c8926c1995117bce.jpg)

Comment: This question is semi-related, and answer(s) should provide the information you want: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27258/how-does-corruption-spread?rq=1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The hollow wont spread accross jungle biomes and crimson as stated on the [wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Containing_the_Hallow/Corruption).

> Despite its friendly looks, the Hallow is only slightly less dangerous
>   than the Corruption or Crimson. It spreads almost completely in the
>   same way as the Corruption except that it cannot spread through the
>   Jungle.

**Containment**

If you do not wish to have your world turned into just Hallow and Corruption/Crimson or even if you want to completely purify your world, containment is key. A simple and also the best way of containment is making straight tunnels from the surface down to the Underworld (commonly called Hellevators) that are three block wide. An easier way would be to place block from the opposite biome of what your are containing around it(Example: Surrounding the Corruption with Hallowed) to stop the spread. The obvious drawback to this plan is that you will have to deal with the biome you're using to contain the other biome with.

**Protecting the Jungle**

Since the Corruption/Crimson cannot spread past Hallow, and the Hallow cannot spread past the Jungle, you can line the edges of your Jungle with Hallowed blocks to prevent damage to it. This will however only prevent surface spreading.
Your question is sort of answered here : [How does corruption spread?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27258/how-does-corruption-spread?rq=1)

Comment: thanks but in gamepedia I read that sunflowers cannot stop hallow spreading. what about hallow ?

Comment: @Mohammad 4+ tile wide shaft or complete extermination are your only options short of editing the world file for that (or don't go into hardmode, ha).

Comment: Why is this accepted? This answer is incorrect.

Comment: And indeed the corruption cant be stopped by sunflowers anymore, ill remove that part from my answer and try and find a correct solution.

Comment: It should all be correct now, could the downvoters reconsider their downvote?