# How to stop Evil or hallow from ruining my pylon system?

Tags: terraria, terraria-console

I recently activated Hard mode in my terraria world and the spread of the evil and hallow biomes stopped like 3 of my pylons from working since the villagers were kicked out of their homes is there a way to stop or fix this easily?

Comment: Related: [How does corruption spread?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27258/how-does-corruption-spread)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I save the world from the spread of Hallow and Corruption/Crimson?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41839/how-can-i-save-the-world-from-the-spread-of-hallow-and-corruption-crimson)